# How do I Quick-edit CSS in Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, css, preferences

Some editors have a facility where you can jump to the CSS definition of HTML code by a shortcut key or context menu pick. Eg: Quick Edit \ Ctrl-E in Dreamweaver.
Is there such a facility in Visual Studio Code?
Is there an extension that provides same?

Answer (score 1):

## CSS PEAK

This extension allows to peak CSS class definitions. Here is the [extention](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pranaygp.vscode-css-peek#:%7E:text=(%20Ctrl%2BShift%2BF12%20),the%20symbol%20(%20Ctrl%2Bhover%20))

Comment: Thanks but does not seem to work for me. Context-menu Peek\Peek definition, F12, or alt-F12 just says "no definition found for myclassname". Dreamweaver Quick-Edit works but I prefer working in VSCode.

Comment: I tried restarting VS Code and it seemed to work for me then.

Answer (score 0):

Default key for the definition in Visual studio is `F12`

For the list of keys you can check here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019